# A problem on sequence of real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let  {$a_n $} be defined by 
$$a_n =a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}},n>1, a_0=4$$
Prove that $45 <a_{1000}<45.1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I tried. but not putting that because I am just learning it's typing method. And it's being complicated for me to typing lot of things.

Comment: Hint. One has $a_n^2 = \left(a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}\right)^2 = a_{n-1}^2+2+\dfrac{1}{a_{n-1}^2}$, giving a telescoping sum, then use the fact the sequence is strictly increasing.

Comment: This is much more than a hint.

Comment: Hmm. Unless 30 decimal place accuracy is somehow insufficient Mathematica says that $a_{1000}\approx 44.92699$. This is also compatible with what I could do with Olivier's nice hint. Both the lower and the upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this has been done a hundred times yet, but anyway... We clearly have $a_n>0$, hence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is increasing. Let us set $b_n=a_n^2$. We have $b_0=16$ and 
$$ b_{n+1} = a_{n+1}^2 = \left(a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^2 \geq a_n^2+2 = b_n+2 $$
hence $b_n\geq 16+2n$ and $a_n\geq\sqrt{16+2n}$, so $a_n\geq \sqrt{2016}\geq 44.8998886$. On the other hand
$$ b_{n+1} \leq b_n+2+\frac{1}{16+2n} $$
leads to
$$ b_n \leq 16+2n+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{18}+\ldots+\frac{1}{14+2n}=16+2n+\frac{H_{n+7}-H_7}{2} $$
then to
$$ a_n\leq \sqrt{16+2n+\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{n}{7}\right)} $$
and $a_{1000}\leq 44.9275463$.

Comment: Pretty much what I got following Olivier's hint. +1 of course. This been done a hundred times? Apparently I should spend more time outside my regular tags (and not obsess only about the repetitive trivial congruences)???

Comment: Just to be sure... is the relation between $H_{n+7}-H_7$ and $ln(\frac{n+7}{7})$ based on an equality or an inequality? I am not sure about how $H_n$ compares to $\gamma + ln(n)$... thanks!

Comment: @Taamer: you are correct: by the Hermite-Hadamard inequality, $H_{n+a}-H_n$ is a bit smaller than $\log\left(1+\frac{n}{a}\right)$.